# Prototype.JS and Facebook Like

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, magento-1.5

I have written a code in jQuery that does the following:

1. Connect via Facebook
2. Click Like button
3. Check if liked on Facebook and show content, ask to like if not liked

   ```
       <script>
       $('#loginfb').click( function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            var logstatus="logged in";
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
              console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
            $('#loginfb').empty();
            $('#loginfb').append('<p>Logged In to Facebook</p>');
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
           var url = 'http://facebook.com/bitslabo';
           $('#fblikeblock').html('<div id="pleaselike">like!</div><fb:like id="fbLike" href="'+url+'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>');
           FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
          } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
          }
        },{perms:"friends_likes,user_likes"});
                   });


       $('#getlogin').click( function() {
           FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
               var page_id = "[PAGE ID]";
                   if (response && response.authResponse) {
                       var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                       var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+" and uid="+user_id;
                       FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
                         if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                           console.log("LIKE");
                           $('#container_notlike').hide();
                           $('#container_like').show();

                         } else {
                           console.log("NO LIKEY");
                           $('#container_like').hide();
                           $('#container_notlike').show();
                         }
                       });
         } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
           // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
           // but has not authenticated your app
           alert('Please click "Log in to Facebook"');
         } else {
           alert('Please click "Log in to Facebook"');
           // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
         }
        });

       });
       </script>
   ```

The issue is that the CMS (magento 1.5) that I'm using has prototype.js all over it and there is a jQuery vs. Prototype conflict where jQuery overrides Prototype and disables all the functions of the site.

So, I guess, there are two questions here:

1. How to make the jQuery script run and not affect prototype scripts?
2. How to write the same thing I described above in Prototype?

I hope that made sense! Thanks in advance!